# Django query omitting expected results

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

I must perform a query on a large database with a somewhat intricate modeling, which I will try to abridge below:

```
class ScreeningItem(models.Model):
    # other fields
    receivedItem = models.OneToOneField(ReceivedItem, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class ReceivedItem(models.Model):
    # other fields
    dossier = models.ForeignKey(Dossier, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Dossier(models.Model):
    # other fields
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField('SubjectTypes', through='Subjects',
                                      through_fields=('dossier', 'subjectType'))

class Subject(models.Model):
    main = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    dossier = models.ForeignKey(Dossier, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    subjectType =  models.ForeignKey(SubjectType, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class SubjectType(models.Model):
    # other fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Now, the problem is that I must find in `ScreeningItem` table items when the far, far away related field `SubjectType.name` contains specific words. No, worse. As you can see below, there's a parent-child self reference in that model, and I must look for those specific words in the related `SujectType`, its parent, and its grandparent, in case they exist.

My attempt:

```
exp = 'something'
queryset = ScreeningItem.objects.filter(
    Q(receivedItem__dossier__subjects__subjecttype__name__iregex=exp) |     
    Q(receivedItem__dossier__subjects__subjecttype__parent__name__iregex=exp) |     
    Q(receivedItem__dossier__subjects__subjecttype__parent__parent__name__iregex=exp))
```

However, when I received a number of records much below I was expecting, I checked the database and discovered, for my astonishment, that there were many `ScreeningItem` which had a `ReceivedItem` which had a `Dossier` which was related to `SubjectTypes` which had the word I was searching for.

Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to disclose the content here. So I wrote the test routine below:

```
def test():
    exp = 'something'  # valid and equal both for Python and MySQL regular expression engines
    re_exp = re.compile(exp, re.IGNORECASE)
    queryset_1 = ScreeningItem.objects.filter(
        Q(receivedItem__dossier__subjects__subjecttype__name__iregex=exp) |     
        Q(receivedItem__dossier__subjects__subjecttype__parent__name__iregex=exp) |     
        Q(receivedItem__dossier__subjects__subjecttype__parent__parent__name__iregex=exp))     
    set_1 = set(queryset_1.values_list('id', flat=True))
    print(len(set_1))

    queryset_2 = GnomoItemTriagem.objects.filter(receivedItem__dossier__isnull=False)
    set_2a = set()
    set_2b = set()
    for item in queryset_2:
        subjects = item.receivedItem.dossier.subjects
        if subjects.filter(
                Q(name__iregex=exp) |
                Q(parent__name__iregex=exp) |
                Q(parent__parent__name__iregex=exp)).count() > 0:
            set_2a.add(item.id)

        for subject in subjects.all():
            if re_exp.findall(subject.name) or\
                (subject.parent and re_exp.findall(subject.parent.name)) or \
                    (subject.parent and subject.parent.parent and re_exp.findall(subject.parent.parent.name)):
                set_2b.add(item.id)

    print(len(set_2a))
    print(len(set_2b))
```

And then my results were

```
1596
21223
21223
```

So how should my 1st query be written in order to also return all the 21223 items required? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to supply sample, redacted data, and show us the results you are geting and the results you are expecting.

Comment: Shouldn't the second be ` Q(subjecttype__name__iregex=exp) ` so with `subjecttype__` as "prefix" in the filtering. Right now it looks likel you are searching for *subjects* with name the `exp`. (perhaps some part of the model that you did not share)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `subjects` is the field in `Dossier` model that relates "many-to-many-ly" to `SubjectType`model through `Subject` model, which is the linking table.

Comment: @VBobCat: ah but then the query should be `receivedItem__dossier__subjects__name__iregex=...` I guess?

Comment: Oh smokes... yes, @WillemVanOnsem it was that. if you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I wonder why the way I did didn't raise an exception, tho...

Comment: @VBobCat: because the name of your model is `subjecttype`. Since you did not define a `related_name` for `parent`, the default name of the name of the relation in "reverse" for parent is `__subjecttype`. So you here basically queried for a `ScreeningItem` with a `receivedItem` with a `dossier` with as `SubjectType` a **child** subjecttype that has a name the query, or the parent of *that* child, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `subjects` is a many-to-many field to `SubjectType`, it already "lands" at that model. The reason that you can query for another `__subjecttype` is because it is visiting the `ForeignKey` of `parent` in "reverse".

Your query thus should look like:

```
queryset = ScreeningItem.objects.filter(
    Q(receivedItem__dossier__subjects__name__iregex=exp) |     
    Q(receivedItem__dossier__subjects__parent__name__iregex=exp) |     
    Q(receivedItem__dossier__subjects__parent__parent__name__iregex=exp)
)
```

The reason it did not error is because your `parent` relation has no `related_name`. So that means that the default `related_name_query` for your `parent` relation is `subjecttype`. As a result you make a query that where you look for `ScreeningItem` with a `receivedItem` with a `dossier` with as `SubjectType` a **child** `SubjectType` that has a name the query, or the parent of *that* child, etc. The *child* part is thus where it goes wrong.